# Не выводит все записи из ACF Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

На странице нужно сделать добавление карточек, сделал через ACF путем регистрации нового поста:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails'); 

    register_post_type('main_cards', array(
        'label'  => null,
        'labels' => array(
            'name'               => 'Карточки на главной', 
            'singular_name'      => 'Карточки на главной', 
            'add_new'            => 'Добавить новую', 
            'add_new_item'       => 'Добавить новую карточку',
            'edit_item'          => 'Редактировать карточку', 
            'new_item'           => 'Новая карточка', 
            'view_item'          => 'Показать карточку',
            'not_found'          => 'Карточка не найдена', 
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'Карточка не найдена в корзине', 
            'menu_name'          => 'Карточки на главной', 
        ),
        'public'              => false,
        'show_ui'             => true, //public dependence
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-format-status',
        'supports'            => array('title', 'thumbnail')
    ) );
```

Потом получил все поля в массив:

```
function get_main_cards() {
    $args = array(
        'orderby'   => 'date',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'main_cards'
    );

    $main_cards = [];

    foreach ( get_posts($args) as $post ) {
        $main_cards_i = get_fields($post->ID);
        $main_cards_i['name'] = $post->post_title;
        $main_cards_i['img'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'image' );
        $main_cards[] = $main_cards_i;
    }

    return $main_cards;
}
```

И на странице вывожу поля таким образом:

```
               <?php


                    foreach ( get_main_cards() as $main_card ): 



                ?>

                <div class="items__col-item">
                    <div class="item__col-inner relative">
                        <div class="item__col-item">
                            <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $main_card['img']; ?>" alt="1"></a>
                            <div class="absolute item__hover d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                               <div class="item__col-btns d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
                                   <a href="#" class="item__col-btn">
                                       Preview Tabor
                                   </a>
                                   <a href="#" class="item__col-btn">
                                       View Details
                                   </a>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="items__col-text text-center">
                        <span class="bold-letters"><?php echo $main_card['name']; ?></span> &mdash; <?php echo $main_card['desc']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php
                            endforeach;
                ?>
```

Но проблема в том что в массив попадает только 5 записей, а следующие при добавлении через админку просто не записываются в массив и не выводятся. В чем может быть проблема, кто знает? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `get_posts()` есть предустановленные параметры, в том числе `numberposts=5`.

Сделайте так:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'     => 'date',
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'post_type'   => 'main_cards',
    'numberposts' => -1,
);
```

Comment: Спасибо) работает!

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.